# How to use keyboard input to do something?

Tags: javascript, html, button, windows-8, keyboard

I have a button on screen. If the user were to press "a" on his physical keyboard then the button should register that keyboard event as a click. I haven't found any documentation regarding this on the Windows 8 Dev portal, but maybe I haven't searched enough. But if anyone has had luck with the same, please assist me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can registrer a `keydown`/`keyup`/`keypress`-event. And use the normalized `event.which` to detect the key:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
    // A = 65
    // Z = 90

    if ( event.which === 65 ) {
        // key pressed is A
        $("button").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

You can also use a library like [mousetrap.js](http://craig.is/killing/mice) <sub><sup>(Take a look at Global bindings)</sup></sub>:

```
Mousetrap.bind('a', function() { 
    $("button").trigger("click");
});
```